# ElasticSearch NEST library to retrieve certain fields

Tags: elasticsearch, selecteditem, nest

Trying to achieve following,

- Retrieve articles that match given id and genre
- Retrieve selected fields for matching records

I have tried this with Sense(chrome plugin),

```
POST /d3acampaign/article/_search
        {
            "fields": ["title","genre"] ,
            "query": {
                "filtered": {
                    "filter": {
                        "bool": {
                            "must": [{
                                    "term": {
                                    "id": "6"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                    "term": {
                                    "genre": "metal"
                                }
                            }]
                        }
                    }
               }
            }
        }
```

For C# code i am trying to build the query using following construct,

```
        FilterContainer fc = null;
        TermFilter title = new TermFilter()
        {
            Field = "id",
            Value = "6",
        };

        TermFilter genre = new TermFilter()
        {
            Field = "genre",
            Value = "metal",
        };

        fc = title & genre;
        QueryContainer qc = new FilteredQuery() { Filter = fc };
        var searchRequest = new SearchRequest
        {
            SearchType = Elasticsearch.Net.SearchType.QueryAndFetch,
            Query = qc,
            Indices = new IndexNameMarker[] {"journal"},
            Types = new TypeNameMarker[] { "article" },                
        };


        var r = client.SearchAsync<Article>(searchRequest);


        var l = (List<Article>) r.Result.Documents;
```

I am able to run this query and get matching records, but i amnt sure how to specify selected fields to retrieve. Let me know what can be changed in C# code to specify necessary fields.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This one should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28773772/how-to-use-pocos-with-fields-in-elasticsearch-net-nest/28781331#28781331

Comment: Thanks Rob for your response, can this be added to SearchRequest like how we are setting Query, Indices, etc?

Comment: Yes, let me prepare an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28773772/how-to-use-pocos-with-fields-in-elasticsearch-net-nest/28781331#28781331) answer you can modify your request object as follow:

```
var searchRequest = new SearchRequest
{
    ...
    Fields = new List<PropertyPathMarker>
    {
        Property.Path<Article>(p => p.YourField)
    }
};
```

or if you will decide to use [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/search-request-source-filtering.html):

```
var searchRequest = new SearchRequest
{
    ...
    Source = new SourceFilter
    {
        Include = new []
        {
            Property.Path<Article>(p => p.YourField)
        }
    } 
};
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried following change but that results in 0 matching records, 
`code`
  var searchRequest = new SearchRequest
  {
   SearchType = Elasticsearch.Net.SearchType.QueryAndFetch,
   Query = qc,
   Indices = new IndexNameMarker[] {"d3acampaign"},
   Types = new TypeNameMarker[] { "article" },
   //Fields = new List<PropertyPathMarker>
   //            {
   //                Property.Path<Article>(p => p.title),
   //                Property.Path<Article>(p => p.Id)
   //            }
  };

  var r = client.SearchAsync<Article>(searchRequest);


  var l = (List<Article>) r.Result.Documents;

Comment: If you are using Fields in request you wont be able to retrive documents. This is why I suggested source filtering. Check attached answer for more details.

Comment: That helped. Thanks for your help