# ElasticSearch- Using Fields doesn't return any documents on Nest

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

When I query without Fields as below, I get results.documents

```
  var results = ElasticClient.Search<Product>(s => s
     .Query(q => q
        .Bool(b => b
            .Should(
                sh => sh.MultiMatch(qs => qs
                    .OnFieldsWithBoost(d => d                       
                        .Add("Name", 3.0)
                        .Add("ShortDescription", 2.0))
                    .Type(TextQueryType.BestFields)
                    .Query(key))))));
```

But If i want to return specific fields like that Document count 0, I see only hits. Why dont I get any documents?

```
  var results = ElasticClient.Search<Product>(s => s
     .Query(q => q
        .Bool(b => b
            .Should(
                sh => sh.MultiMatch(qs => qs
                    .OnFieldsWithBoost(d => d                       
                        .Add("Name", 3.0)
                        .Add("ShortDescription", 2.0))
                    .Type(TextQueryType.BestFields)
                    .Query(key))))).Fields(f => f.ProductId, f => f.Name));
```

Comment: [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28773772/how-to-use-pocos-with-fields-in-elasticsearch-net-nest/28781331#28781331) will explain why.